# Can't dispatch payload data with Promise.all

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am trying to dispatch the payload data, but I don't know what I am missing. The dispatch works when I just run axios.get('URL'), but when I change axios.get to Promise.all, it just totally dismisses the payload's data. This should go unsaid, but I'm changing axios.get to Promise.all, because I need axios to get multiple requests, and I need that response data elsewhere in my code. If someone could explain what I am doing wrong that would be a blessing.

getUser.js_________
payload code works

```
    dispatch({
      type: GET_CONTACTS_LOADING,
    });
  
    axios
      .get('/user/')
      .then((res) => {
        dispatch({
          type: GET_CONTACTS_SUCCESS,
          payload: res.data,                            <---I want to get data
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        dispatch({
          type: GET_CONTACTS_FAIL,
          payload: err.response
            ? err.response.data
            : {error: 'Something went wrong, try again'},
        });
      });
  };
```

getUser.js_________
payload code doesn't work

```
   dispatch({
      type: GET_CONTACTS_LOADING,
    });

    const requestOne = axios.get('/user/')
    const requestTwo = axios.get('/user/profile/')


    Promise.all([requestOne,requestTwo ])
      .then((res) => {
        res[1];
        res[2];
        dispatch({
          type: GET_CONTACTS_SUCCESS,
          payload: res.data,                           <---I want to get data
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        dispatch({
          type: GET_CONTACTS_FAIL,
          payload: err.response
            ? err.response.data
            : {error: 'Something went wrong, try again'},
        });
      });
  };
```

Comment: Promise.all returns list of results (if all promises are resolved). That means, if you want data from first request, you need `res[0].data`, or from second request `res[1].data`.

Comment: I just tried and got the same results.

Comment: What gives you console.log(res)?

Comment: It says the data is undefined, but that's also because Its not react to the two urls.

Comment: I don't see any issue in the code, only: what is the purpose of res[1]; res[2]; lines? But they should not affect the axios requests.